# How to load a webpage (NOT in a browser) then get the url of that webpage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, wikipedia

I wanted to make something I saw on Reddit that allows you to get a random Wikipedia article, see its headline then either A (open the article in your browser) or B (get a new random article). To get a random article you would type in this URL "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" but then I would need to reload the URL see what it changed to and then figure out what article I got to. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Breaking the task down into bite sized chunks**:

> get a random Wikipedia article

Cool. This is pretty straight forward. You can either use Python's built-in `urllib2` or the `requests` package. Most people recommend `requests` (`pip install requests`) as it is a higher level library that is a bit simpler to use, but in this case what we are doing is so simple it might be overkill. At any rate:

```
import requests

RANDOM_WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
response = requests.get(RANDOM_WIKI_URL)
data = response.content
url = response.url
```

> see its headline

For this we need to parse the HTML. It's tempting to recommend that you just use a regex to extract the text from the element containing the title but really the proper way to do this sort of thing is to use a library like `BeautifulSoup` (`pip install beautifulsoup4`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
title = soup.select('#firstHeading')[0].get_text()
print title
```

> either A ([...]) or B ([...])

```
print "=" * 80
print "(a): Open in new browser tab"
print "(b): Get new article"
print "(q): Quit"
user_input = raw_input("[a|b|q]: ").lower()

if user_input == 'a':
    ...
elif user_input == 'b':
    ...
elif user_input == 'q':
    ...
```

> open the article in your browser

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

> get a new random article

```
response = requests.get(RANDOM_WIKI_URL)
data = response.content
url = response.url
```

**Putting it all together**:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import webbrowser

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


RANDOM_WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"


def get_user_input():
    user_input = ''
    while user_input not in ('a', 'b', 'q'):
        print '-' * 79
        print "(a): Open in new browser tab"
        print "(b): Get new random article"
        print "(q): Quit"
        print '-' * 79
        user_input = raw_input("[a|b|q]: ").lower()
    return user_input

def main():
    while True:
        print "=" * 79
        print "Retrieving random wikipedia article..."
        response = requests.get(RANDOM_WIKI_URL)
        data = response.content
        url = response.url

        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.select('#firstHeading')[0].get_text()

        print "Random Wikipedia article: '{}'".format(title)
        user_input = get_user_input()
        if user_input == 'q':
            break
        elif user_input == 'a':
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Site:Random` page in Wikipedia returns the [redirection response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) with the destination location:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection
...
```

Most libraries (and all browsers) follow that link automatically, but you can disable it, for example, in [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history):

```
import requests
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random'
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
real_url = response.headers['location']
# then use real_url to fetch the page
```

Alternatively, `requests` provides the redirection history:

```
response = requests.get(url)
real_url = response.history[-1].headers['location']
```

In the latter case, `response` already contains the page you need, so that's a simpler way.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using "requests"?

Comment: @Beta_Penguin certainly, that's doable also with the standard `urllib2`, as @dv1337 shows.

Answer (score 0):

1. URL - you can get the url with urllib2 response.geturl()
2. Wiki header - you can parse the header with the BeautifulSoup package
3. Browser - You can open the url in a web browser with the webbrowser.open(url)

Here's simple working example:

```
import urllib2
import webbrowser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

while (True):
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')
    headline = BeautifulSoup(response.read()).html.title.string
    url = response.geturl()
    print "The url:          " +url
    print "The headline:     " + headline

    x = raw_input("Press: [A - Open in browser] [B - Get a new random article] [Anything else to exit]\n>")
    if x  == "A":
        webbrowser.open(url) #open in browser
    elif x == "B":
        continue # get a new random article
    else:
        break #exit
```